# Flutter app crashes when lunching it on real iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, crash

We developed a flutter app and tested it on a lot of emulators(iOs/android) and they worked fine then we built apk file and tested it on android and it worked fine, but when we built ipa for iOS the app just crashes on start up.

We tried to debug on a real Iphone but the app work it's only on the release that it crashes.
also tried `flutter clean` several time with no luck.

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-YE)
    • Flutter version 3.13.8 on channel stable at
      /Users/albusairi/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 6c4930c4ac (5 days ago), 2023-10-18 10:57:55 -0500
    • Engine revision 767d8c75e8
    • Dart version 3.1.4
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/albusairi/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro (mobile)  • DC34EB5F-3761-4965-94AF-EB8A38E8FE50 •ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Are you building a dev/debug or a release build?  A debug build only works when run from the debugger.

Comment: @Paulw11 Iam building in a release using `flutter build ipa`

Comment: try to use Xcode to test your app on real device

Answer (score 0):

We managed to make a stop the app form crashing, the cause of the crash was a package used in the app called [internet_connection_checker 1.0.0+1](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker/install).

Why does it crash the app we are not sure, but we think it's one of two:

1. We didn't implement it correctly to suit iOs devices. (working on it)
2. There is a bug in the package.

We will try to solve the problem if we couldn't then will will try another package.

Thank you.